# Sudoers - Allow one specific command as a specific user

Tags: sudo

I have a PHP script that needs to call a python script. However, I don't want the python script to be executed as www-data (php user) but as pycert. Therefore, I tried to allow www-data to execute the script in the sudoers file but that does not seem to work.
PHP code :

```
exec("timeout --preserve-status -k 10 15s sudo -u pycert /bin/python /var/www/files/certs/creation/cert.py $file", $resulta, $result);
```

Visudo file:

```
www-data ALL=(pycert:pycert) NOPASSWD:/bin/python /var/www/files/certs/creation/cert.py /var/www/files/certs/creation/cert-[0-9a-ZA-Z]+
```

This is auth.log :

```
sudo: www-data : command not allowed ; TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/www/files.git ; USER=pycert ; GROUP=pycert ; COMMAND=/bin/python /var/www/files/certs/creation/cert.py /var/www/files/certs/creation/cert-Wi1S9a
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there's no such thing as a "visudo file". Visudo is an editor for changing sudoers files.

Secondly, you omitted to mention what distribution of Linux this is - which might have given us some clue as to whether there is an Mandatory Access Control system in play.

Thirdly, you tried to build the end result rather than breaking down the problem into tasks which can be easily reproduced on demand, i.e. trying to implement the sudo operation using a normal interactive user account.

Fourthly, you didn't read the manual. Particularly the bit that says "Note that these are not regular expressions". `[0-9a-ZA-Z]+` does NOT match a repeating set of alpha chars and digits, it matches a single aplpha char OR digit FOLLOWED by a literal '+'.

Try...

```
user ALL=(pycert:pycert) NOPASSWD:/bin/python /var/www/files/certs/creation/cert.py /var/www/files/certs/creation/cert-*
```